# Javascript Image() missing `Origin` header when loading src

Tags: javascript, html, cors

Having a fun time with canvas and particularly Google Chrome. Right now I'm loading an image via Javascript that is to be used in a canvas wrapped with EaselJS. Here's how I'm loading the image (hosted on S3):

```
imageLoad: function(imageUrl, imageId) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  image.imageId = imageId
  image.onload = this.handleImageLoad;
  image.src = imageUrl;
}
```

Images are stored on an Amazon S3 bucket with the following CORS properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>1</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

## The Problem

It appears that the browser is not setting the `Origin` header when loading the image above. This particularly happens if the image has already been loaded outside of javascript and cached by the browser. However - and here's where it gets weird - once a *second* attempt is made to load the image using Javascript, then CORS security issues go away (and apparently the browser sets an `Origin` header).

We've tested this behavior multiple times, and also confirmed it by setting up a server that forces CORS headers with each response. It does appear that the browser is not adding `Origin` headers even when asked explicitly.

## The Question

So given all of this information, what can we do to work around the problem? Can Amazon CloudFront be forced to always add CORS headers? Is there a problem with `image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"`?

Comment: Please post correct answers to this question. if you were able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was simply putting Fastly CDN (http://fastly.com) in front of our S3 bucket. A not-so-pretty way of doing things, but we were able to inject custom headers under the "Settings" section of our service.

This was the solution to this particular problem.